# Conversion failed when converting varchar value to data type int in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff, dateadd

I am having some difficulty getting the difference between two time values in SQL. I want to select all the values that have less than 5 seconds difference between the start and stop of the date value.

My data looks like this

```
Stop
-----------------------    
2017-10-04 16:32:06:000

Start
-----------------------    
2017-10-04 16:32:02:000
```

The above scenario would be one of those calls. My code in the where clause to obtain only values in the data that are less than 5 seconds:

```
  datediff(second, cast(stop as int), cast(start as int)) < 5
```

I also tried just datediff without the cast as int and still received the same error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar vlue '2017-10-04 20:58:46:000' to data type int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `datediff()` add seconds to the start time:

```
where stop < dateadd(second, 5, start)
```

You should be storing the date/times as date/time types, not as strings.  However, you at least have a standard format, so you can be explicit about the type casts if you like:

```
where convert(datetime, stop) < dateadd(second, 5, convert(datetime, start))
```

This is actually  more accurate, because `datediff()` counts "time boundaries" between two values, not actual seconds.

The main thing with `datediff()`, though, is that the arguments are not integers.  So you could do:

```
datediff(second, start, stop) < 5
```

But the first method is better.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you don't need the casts to get the diff in seconds ...

```
select datediff (SECOND,start, stop) from test
```

Just tot test it ...

```
select 1 
where ((select datediff (SECOND,start, stop) from test) > 5)
```

datediff() query:
 [image]
test table:

[image]